# wpdb query with dynamic column name?

Tags: query, columns

How can i dynamically set a column name in $wpdb query? i tried

```
$which_column = 'phone';
$data_check = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT '.$which_column.' FROM wp_shopping_preferences WHERE wp_user_id = '$id'");
```

but it doesn't work. This however does work

```
$data_check = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT phone FROM wp_shopping_preferences WHERE wp_user_id = '$id'");
```

I need the columns to be set dynamically for a shortcode i am building

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a syntax error by the looks of it. You are using `"` to open the string, and `'` to close it. Use this:

```
$which_column = 'phone';
$data_check = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT " . $which_column . " FROM wp_shopping_preferences WHERE wp_user_id = '$id'");
```

Fun fact: when using double quotes (`"`), you can directed insert a variable into the string without closing it~

```
$which_column = 'phone';
$data_check = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT $which_column FROM wp_shopping_preferences WHERE wp_user_id = '$id'");
```

**EDIT**

I noticed that you have `$id` at the end of the query also being added. **If this is a user-submitted value`you must use [`$wpdb->prepare`][1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to ensure it's sanitized properly. See below:

```
$which_column = 'phone';
$data_check = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT $which_column FROM wp_shopping_preferences WHERE wp_user_id = %d",
        $id 
    )
);
```

The extra line breaks are unnecessary, but only to demenstrate what's happening. I've replaced`$id` with `%d`, which will typecast `$id` as a numeric value. Check out [`$wpdb->prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) for more options.

Comment: tx i didn't realise WP uses two different ways of declaring a $variable within a query. '$id' vs ". $which_column . ' or '$id' vs $which_column

Comment: See Edit above for a more secure query.